# How to merge audio and video file in android

Tags: android, html, audio, video, mp4parser

Thanks for the great [mp4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) lib, i have few queries related to audio video muxing.

We used the below code in android and tried, but we are not getting the expected output, We have kept a working mp4 file in the specific directory and trying but no luck.

Here we get the merged audio and video, but audio gets appended to video. And the appended audio will not play but simply it increases the width of video.

Any help from geeks.

Here is the code,

```
    File sdCard = Environment.getDataDirectory();

    String videofilepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/video.mp4";
    String audiofilepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/audio.aac";
    File file=new File(videofilepath);

    H264TrackImpl h264Track = new H264TrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl(videofilepath));
    AACTrackImpl aacTrack = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl(audiofilepath));

    Movie movie = new Movie();
    movie.addTrack(h264Track);
    movie.addTrack(aacTrack);


    Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);

    FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/video.mp4")).getChannel();
    mp4file.writeContainer(fc);
    fc.close();
```

Comment: Any errors in Logcat?

Answer (score 2):

1. We can Merge `.m4a`, `.aac`, `.3gp`  audio files with an `.mp4` video file in android.
   2) `.mp3` audio files cannot be merged with video files.

The below code works for merging `.mp4` audio and blank video (no sound):

```
public class Search extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Boolean> {

    private final Search self = this;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    VideoView mVideoView;
    ImageView back, next;
    String path;
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    String songpath, songname;
    String TAG = "Logcat";
    String[] fileList;

    String audiopath = "/sdcard/dubmash/audio.m4a";
    String videopath = "/sdcard/dubmash/video.`mp4`";
    String output;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            songpath = i.getStringExtra("songpath");
            songname = i.getStringExtra("songname");
            Log.e("Search Class :song name", songname);
            Log.e("Search Class :song path", songpath);
        }


        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back);
        next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.next);
        String audio = audiopath;
        String video = videopath;
        output = "/sdcard/dubmash/" + songname + ".mp4";

        Log.e("FILE", "audio:" + audio + " video:" + video + " out:" + output);

        try {
            mux(video, audio, output);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Toast.makeText(Search.this, "Please Record Again ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        try {
            //Delete video file
            File file = new File(videopath);
            boolean deleted = file.delete();
            //Delete Audio file
            File files = new File(audiopath);
            boolean deleted1 = files.delete();


            mVideoView.setVideoPath(output);
            mVideoView.requestFocus();
            mVideoView.start();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Toast.makeText(Search.this, "File Not Find", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playvideoplayer);
        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                mVideoView.setVideoPath(output);
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
                mVideoView.start();

            }
        });

        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Search.this, HomePage.class);
                i.putExtra("showdubs", "dubs");
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Search.this, AlbumDetailVideo.class);
                i.putExtra("songpath", songpath);
                i.putExtra("songname", songname);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Boolean> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new EditMovieTask(self, args.getInt("type"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Boolean> loader, Boolean succeed) {
        getSupportLoaderManager().destroyLoader(loader.getId());
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Boolean> loader) {
    }

    public static class EditMovieTask extends AsyncTaskLoader<Boolean> {

        private int mType;

        public EditMovieTask(Context context, int type) {
            super(context);
            mType = type;
            forceLoad();
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean loadInBackground() {

            switch (mType) {
                case 0:
                    //         return append();
                case 1:
                    //       return crop();
                case 2:
                    //     return subTitle();
            }

            return false;
        }


    }

    public boolean mux(String videoFile, String audioFile, String outputFile) {
        Movie video;
        try {
            video = new MovieCreator().build(videoFile);
            Log.e("Audio Video", "1");
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Audio Video", "2");
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Audio Video", "3");
            return false;
        }

        Movie audio;
        try {

            audio = new MovieCreator().build(audioFile);
            Log.e("Audio Video", "4");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Audio Video", "5");
            return false;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Audio Video", "6");
            return false;
        }

        Track audioTrack = audio.getTracks().get(0);
        video.addTrack(audioTrack);

        Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(video);
        Log.e("Audio Video", "8");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            Log.e("Audio Video", "9");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        BufferedWritableFileByteChannel byteBufferByteChannel = new BufferedWritableFileByteChannel(fos);
        try {
            Log.e("Audio Video", "10");
            out.writeContainer(byteBufferByteChannel);
            byteBufferByteChannel.close();
            Log.e("Audio Video", "11");
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static class BufferedWritableFileByteChannel implements WritableByteChannel {
        //    private static final int BUFFER_CAPACITY = 1000000;
        private static final int BUFFER_CAPACITY = 10000000;

        private boolean isOpen = true;
        private final OutputStream outputStream;
        private final ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
        private final byte[] rawBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_CAPACITY];

        private BufferedWritableFileByteChannel(OutputStream outputStream) {
            this.outputStream = outputStream;
            this.byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(rawBuffer);
            Log.e("Audio Video", "13");
        }

        @Override
        public int write(ByteBuffer inputBuffer) throws IOException {
            int inputBytes = inputBuffer.remaining();

            if (inputBytes > byteBuffer.remaining()) {
                Log.e("Size ok ", "song size is ok");
                dumpToFile();
                byteBuffer.clear();

                if (inputBytes > byteBuffer.remaining()) {
                    Log.e("Size ok ", "song size is not okssss ok");
                    throw new BufferOverflowException();
                }
            }

            byteBuffer.put(inputBuffer);

            return inputBytes;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isOpen() {
            return isOpen;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            dumpToFile();
            isOpen = false;
        }

        private void dumpToFile() {
            try {
                outputStream.write(rawBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.position());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }


    private void muxing() {

        String outputFile = "";

        try {

            root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            String audio = root + "/" + "audio.mp3";
            String video = root + "/" + "rohit.mp4";


            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "final2.mp4");
            file.createNewFile();
            outputFile = file.getAbsolutePath();


            MediaExtractor videoExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
            videoExtractor.setDataSource(video);

            MediaExtractor audioExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
            audioExtractor.setDataSource(audio);

            Log.d(TAG, "Video Extractor Track Count " + videoExtractor.getTrackCount());
            Log.d(TAG, "Audio Extractor Track Count " + audioExtractor.getTrackCount());

            MediaMuxer muxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFile, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

            videoExtractor.selectTrack(0);
            MediaFormat videoFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
            int videoTrack = muxer.addTrack(videoFormat);

            audioExtractor.selectTrack(0);
            MediaFormat audioFormat = audioExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
            int audioTrack = muxer.addTrack(audioFormat);

            Log.d(TAG, "Video Format " + videoFormat.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "Audio Format " + audioFormat.toString());

            boolean sawEOS = false;
            int frameCount = 0;
            int offset = 100;
            int sampleSize = 256 * 1024;
            ByteBuffer videoBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
            ByteBuffer audioBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo videoBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo audioBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();


            videoExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
            audioExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);

            muxer.start();

            while (!sawEOS) {
                videoBufferInfo.offset = offset;
                videoBufferInfo.size = videoExtractor.readSampleData(videoBuf, offset);


                if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
                    sawEOS = true;
                    videoBufferInfo.size = 0;

                } else {
                    videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = videoExtractor.getSampleTime();
                    videoBufferInfo.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME;
                    muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrack, videoBuf, videoBufferInfo);
                    videoExtractor.advance();


                    frameCount++;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + " Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + videoBufferInfo.size / 1024);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + " Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024);

                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "frame:" + frameCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            boolean sawEOS2 = false;
            int frameCount2 = 0;
            while (!sawEOS2) {
                frameCount2++;

                audioBufferInfo.offset = offset;
                audioBufferInfo.size = audioExtractor.readSampleData(audioBuf, offset);

                if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
                    sawEOS2 = true;
                    audioBufferInfo.size = 0;
                } else {
                    audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = audioExtractor.getSampleTime();
                    audioBufferInfo.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME;
                    muxer.writeSampleData(audioTrack, audioBuf, audioBufferInfo);
                    audioExtractor.advance();


                    Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + " Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + videoBufferInfo.size / 1024);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + " Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024);

                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "frame:" + frameCount2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            muxer.stop();
            muxer.release();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Mixer Error 1 " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Mixer Error 2 " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what was wrong with this answer. It seems to be working as expected for me. I use an edited version of the above code after I have muxed together a number of video files into one and a number of audio files into one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with your output file name which is the as input. try to change name of output file.

```
FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/video_out.mp4")).getChannel();
```

Comment: Thanks Nawaz, i tried the above code, still the problem is persisting, if video is of 10 seconds and audio is of 1 minute, then merged file will display 1 minute as duration but we will be able to see only 10 seconds of video and no audio will be played. So did you tried anytime mp3 parser?. did it worked successfully for you?

Comment: I used mp4parser for merging videos and it worked great for me.

Comment: Oh man, you are great, can you please please post me a sample working project in android, or please share it in drop box and give me link yaar, it will be really helpful for me, Please provide me a sample working project thats all i want. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Hi Nawaz, can you please help by posting a sample example project for merging audio and video in Android. please... thanks

Comment: I used very old version of mp4parser and separate code is not available. I will suggest you to upgrade your project to Android Studio.

Comment: I upgraded the android studio and included the gradle version of lib, did all. But my video and audio are not mixing :(

Comment: I know its not correct to ask but i have tried adding 
compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.5.4'
in dependencies but it gives me Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.5.4
can you help me out ?

Comment: Hi, if you add dependency version 1.0.5.4, it will compile perfectly fine, if not it could be either u are using older version of JDK or something else. Check the logs of gradle, it will be helpful. If you need more help drop comment. thank u

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to this but this will be helpful for someone who'll need this :

A little advice always try to this things using **AsynchTask** which gives you the power to this stuff in background as it has its method named **doInBackground()** Well try and catch are also the good things which will help you in the same way.

There is a little changes in your code, implement it and you'll get the result.

```
File sdCard = Environment.getDataDirectory();

String videofilepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/video.mp4";
String audiofilepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/audio.aac";
File file=new File(videofilepath);

Movie videoOutput = null;
Movie audioOutput = null;

try{
            videoOutput = MovieCreator.build(videoFilePath);
            audioOutput = MovieCreator.build(audioFilePath);
        }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Track> finalTrack = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Track track : videoOutput.getTracks()){
            if(track.getHandler().equals("vide"))
                finalTrack.add(track);
        }

        for(Track track : audioOutput.getTracks()){
            if(track.getHandler().equals("soun"))
                finalTrack.add(track);
        }

        videoOutput.setTracks(finalTrack);

Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);

String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/video.mp4"    

try{
FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath)).getChannel();
mp4file.writeContainer(fc);
fc.close();
}catch(Exception e){
   //catch exception 
}
return filePath;
```

Here filePath is the path of the main output merged file which is stored in the assigned place. you go and check it by playing it in your video player.

Happy Learning. Fell free to ask anything if you want to. :)

Comment: what was thus Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);
movie variable

Answer (score 0):

```
String videofilepath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/append.mp4";
String audiofilepath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/originalSound.aac";

AACTrackImpl aacTrack = null;
try {
    aacTrack = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl(audiofilepath));
    Movie countVideo = MovieCreator.build(videofilepath);
    Movie movie = new Movie();
    movie.addTrack(countVideo.getTracks().get(0));
    movie.addTrack(aacTrack);

    Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);

    FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/video.mp4")).getChannel();
    mp4file.writeContainer(fc);
    fc.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```